# Calling the same function with different functions called inside

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I hope my title is clear. Let me explain. I have 4 buttons that do pretty much the same.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    LimiteGlobalSeparador = InputBox("Introduzca la distancia máxima entre huecos en el tubo", "Cuadro de Datos, Separaciones", "")
    Dim a, b, c, d, f, g As New Label
    Dim o, p, q, r, s, t As New Label
    a.Text = "Medida del Tubo"
    b.Text = "Espacio 1"
    c.Text = "Espacio 2"
    d.Text = "Espacio 3"
    f.Text = "Espacio 4"
    g.Text = "Espacio 5"
    For i = 0 To 5
        TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(a, 0, i)
    Next
    If TextBox1.Text <> 0 Then
        For j = 1 To Int(TextBox1.Text)
            Dim x As New List(Of Decimal)
            x = MedTuboFuncPCT()
            For i = 0 To x.Count - 1
                Dim lbl As New Label
                lbl.Text = Math.Round(x(i), 2)
                TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(lbl, j, i)
            Next
            ContadorGlobal = ContadorGlobal + 1
        Next
    Else
    End If

    ContadorGlobal = 0

    Dim h As Integer
    h = Int(TextBox2.Text - TextBox1.Text)
    If TextBox2.Text <> 0 Then
        If h = Int(TextBox2.Text) Then
            For j = 1 To Int(TextBox2.Text)
                Dim x As New List(Of Decimal)
                x = MedTuboFunCTCT()
                For i = 0 To x.Count - 1
                    Dim lbl As New Label
                    lbl.Text = Math.Round(x(i), 2)
                    TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(lbl, j, i)
                Next
                ContadorGlobal = ContadorGlobal + 1
            Next
        Else
            ContadorGlobal = 0
            For j = Int(1) + Int(TextBox1.Text) To (Int(TextBox1.Text) + Int(TextBox2.Text))
                Dim x As New List(Of Decimal)
                x = MedTuboFunCTCT()
                For i = 0 To x.Count - 1
                    Dim lbl As New Label
                    lbl.Text = Math.Round(x(i), 2)
                    TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(lbl, j, i)
                Next
                ContadorGlobal = ContadorGlobal + 1
            Next
        End If
    End If

    ContadorGlobal = 0
    If TextBox3.Text <> 0 Then
        Dim x As New List(Of Decimal)
        x = MedTuboFuncPP()
        For i = 0 To x.Count - 1
            Dim lbl As New Label
            lbl.Text = Math.Round(x(i), 2)
            TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(lbl, 1, i)
        Next
    End If
    If Te180 > 0 Then
        o.Text = "Medida del Tubo"
        p.Text = "Espacio 1"
        q.Text = "Espacio 2"
        r.Text = "Espacio 3"
        s.Text = "Espacio 4"
        t.Text = "Espacio 5"
        For i = 6 To 11
            TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(o, 0, i)
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

So I'm trying to create a Sub and then each button call that sub, so I don't have repeating code in each button like I have now. The only change is here:

One button calls this function. `x = MedTuboFuncPCT().`

Another one calls `x = MedTuboFuncPCTVid()`

Another one calls `x = MedTuboFuncPCTVidBB()`

I don't know how to make a Sub in which I can make this difference. Hope I'm clear enough. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should try to write methods which do one simple thing. As best I can tell, that click event does 5.  If each block was its own sub, you could mix and match the 'generic" ones with the more refined ones as needed: [Single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).  Simplicity is the heart of reusability.  BTW there seems to be a large number of labels created which are never used or disposed

Comment: You should also turn on `Option Strict` so that the IDE can warn you of dubious type conversions.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'm working on doing a program for my company. I'm no programmer, but I know some of the basic stuff and love to program. So the first code I made for this program was big repeating pieces of code over and over again. When I wanted to add something to new the program, I realized that I need to make my code simpler, otherwise I will struggle everytime I try to add something.

Again, thanks for the advice, since what I look is for my code to be simple. And I think you have helped me already in one of my questions!

Edit: All the labels are used btw :)

Comment: Oh yes, you are right! I just run the program and I am not using some labels. My previous code was:
 
a.Text = "Medida del Tubo"
b.Text = "Espacio 1"
c.Text = "Espacio 2"
d.Text = "Espacio 3"
f.Text = "Espacio 4"
g.Text = "Espacio 5"

TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(a, 0, 0)
TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(b, 0, 1)
TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(c, 0, 2)
TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(d, 0, 3)
TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(f, 0, 4)
TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(g, 0, 5)
I tried to use a for loop, but I just realized my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your function and send a value in it so you can change the `x` function

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
  VFunction = 1
  RepeatedCode(VFunction)
End Sub
```

On Button2 `VFunction = 2` and so on. Then create your function.

```
Public Sub RepeatedCode (ByVal VFunction as integer)
    If VFunction = 1 Then
        x = MedTuboFuncPCT()
    ElseIf VFunction = 2 Then
       x = MedTuboFuncPCTVid()
    ElseIf VFunction = 3 Then
       x = MedTuboFuncPCT()
    End If

   'The Rest of your code
```

I belive the `If` condition must be placed inside your `If TextBox1.Text <> 0`
Since it its the only place where I see you used one of the Functions you mentioned

Comment: I think that might work just right! Thanks for the idea. That was exactly what I was looking for.